# Complex vectors in Hilbert space, or, how much is 0.707^2 + (0.707i)^2?

Tags: complex-numbers, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

I am reading **Hidden In Plain Sight 10: How To Program A Quantum Computer** ([https://www.amazon.com/Hidden-Plain-Sight-10-Computer-ebook/dp/B07GPRBYVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GPRBYVC)).

There is something I don't understand.

In chapter 5, the author presents the projection of a complex vector on a coordinate system in Hilbert space (I hope I expressed it correctly...).

As I understand, the author claims that the vector `0.707 + 0.707i` has a magnitude of 1.0, because, supposedly, `0.707^2 + (0.707i)^2 = 1.0`.

But, `0.707^2 + (0.707i)^2` equals `0` (according to my understanding, and according to https://www.google.com/search?q=0.707%5E2%2B%280.707i%29%5E2).

So there must be something I misunderstand in the explanation. The author's explanation includes a diagram, so I'm adding it here as an image:

[image]

What is my mistake?

Comment: The magnitude of a complex number $x+iy$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: @ParasKhosla thanks. Do you mean that this is the **definition** of _the magnitude of a complex number_? Or is it the result of a more basic property of complex numbers?

Comment: This is the magnitude of a complex number by definition. The magnitude being $1$ is an approximation, since $0.707$ is not exactly equal to $1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thanks. If you post it as an answer then I will accept it...

Comment: You don't seem to being taking into account that **the imaginary part is real,** by definition.  The imaginary part of $a+bi$ is $b$, not $bi$.

Comment: @saulspatz I see. So I understand now why the text is accurate. However, from the geometric perspective, I'd expect to square the "full" $0.707i$ to apply Pythagoras' theorem, but I understand now (from Paras Khosla) that there is a different definition for the magnitude of complex numbers...

Comment: No, it's the exact same definition.  But $i$ is an axis.  If you are doing the pythagorean theorem you are finding the hypotenuse of a triangle with *REAL* sides.  SO this triangle in the real axis has a side of real LENGTH $0.707$> and on the imaginary axis is has a sid of real LENGTH also $0.707$.  The $i$ is the "direction"; it is *not* the length.

Comment: "However, from the geometric perspective, I'd expect to square the "full" 0.707i to apply Pythagoras' theorem"  No, you would not.  You square the lengths of the sides of a triangle.  The sides of a triangle are *real* number (postive) lengths.  The $i$ is a "direction".  It does not affect the length at all.  The *length* is still $0.707$

Comment: If it helps at all, the magnitude is meant to measure ‘how much’ of some vector there is. You drew a unit circle. Forget the complex stuff. Any vector extending from the center of the unit circle to the circle itself will have magnitude of simply 1 if the circle is embedded in some flat space like the complex plane or real plane, where the standard norm/magnitude definition is chosen. To check your understanding, what’s the magnitude of $n(0.707 + i*0.707)$? What about $n(0.707-i*0.707)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complex number $a + bi$ has a *real* part that is $a$.  $a$ is a *real* number.  And a complex number has an *imaginary* part that is $b$.  The imaginary part is *also* a real number.  It does *not* include the $i$.  It is the "coefficient" of the $i$.

When he says we square the real part and square the imaginary part and add them together you are squaring $a$ and $b$ and getting $a^2 + b^2$.  You are *not* squaring $a$ and $bi$.

So in this case $|0.707 + 0.707i| = \sqrt{ 0.707^2 +0.707^2} =\sqrt{\frac 12 + \frac 12} = 1$.